# How to correctly use the GET SET command of redis in nodejs under concurrency?

Tags: node.js, redis

In my concurrent project, I need to get a value in redis then update it and set in redis. Like the following code, the result I expected should be 3000, but I can't get the correct result. The sequence maybe wrong, may GET GET SET SET or GET SET SET GET, etc. How can I get the right sequence and correct result? Should I use some lock?

```
import * as redis from 'redis';

let config: redis.ClientOpts = {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 6379
};

let redisClient: redis.RedisClient = new redis.RedisClient(config);
redisClient.set('num', '0');

(async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        await add ();
    }
})();

(async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        await add ();
    }
})();

(async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        await add ();
    }
})();

// I know incr command, this is just an example.
async function add () { 
    let numStr: string = await get('num');
    let num: number = Number(numStr);
    num++;
    await set('num', String(num));
    console.log(num);
}

async function get (key: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>((resovle, reject) => {
        redisClient.get(key, (err: Error, reply: string) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                reject(err);
            }
            resovle(reply);
        })
    });
}

async function set (key: string, value: string): Promise<string> {  
    return new Promise<string>((resovle, reject) => {
        redisClient.set(key, value, (err: Error, reply: string) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                reject(err);
            }
            resovle(reply);
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Redis provides a more flexible way to 'atomically' perform transactions using the MULTI-EXEC approach.

Imagine you're working on a banking system, and a customer requests for a monet transfer. You need to first discount the money from the client's account and then deposit it into the other account. In between these operations, one of them might fail. So, we use transactions.

A transaction is atomic, meaning that either all of the operations happen all none of them do. Databases have locking and concurrency management implementation that ensures this occurs, whiles it does not affect the system's performance drastically.

Example:

```
var redis  = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient(), multi;

async function add () { 
    multi = client.multi();
    let numStr: string = await multi.get('num');
    let num: number = Number(numStr);
    num++;
    await multi.set('num', String(num));
    multi.exec(function (err, replies) {
        console.log(replies);});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I wanna update not only number but also string.

Comment: I tried transactions, it don't work in this situation. I am trying to solve this by lock. ref: https://redis.io/topics/distlock

Comment: Okay great. Seems to address your issue. Good luck, and do share your progress here.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it, thanks everyone. Here is my code. ref: https://redis.io/topics/distlock

```
import * as redis from 'redis';
import * as crypto from 'crypto';

const lockScript: string = 'return redis.call("set", KEYS[1], ARGV[1], "NX", "PX", ARGV[2])';
const unlockScript: string = 'if redis.call("get", KEYS[1]) == ARGV[1] then return redis.call("del", KEYS[1]) else return 0 end';

let config: redis.ClientOpts = {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 6379
};

let redisClient: redis.RedisClient = new redis.RedisClient(config);
redisClient.set('num', '0');

(async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        await add ();
    }
})();

(async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        await add ();
    }
})();

(async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        add ();
    }
})();

async function add () {
    let resourse: string = 'lock:num';
    let uniqueStr: string = crypto.randomBytes(10).toString('hex');
    await attemptLock(resourse, uniqueStr);
    let num: number = Number(await get('num'));
    num++;
    console.log(num);
    await set('num', String(num));
    await unlock(resourse, uniqueStr);
}

async function loop (resourse: string, uniqueStr: string, ttl?: string) {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(async () => {
            let result: any = await lock(resourse, uniqueStr, ttl);
            resolve(!!result);
        }, 10);
    });
}

async function attemptLock (resourse: string, uniqueStr: string, ttl?: string) {
    let result = await loop(resourse, uniqueStr, ttl);
    if (result) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return attemptLock(resourse, uniqueStr, ttl);
    }
}

async function lock (resourse: string, uniqueStr: string, ttl?: string) {
    ttl = ttl ? ttl : '30000';

    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        redisClient.eval(lockScript, 1, resourse, uniqueStr, ttl, (err: Error, reply: any) =>{
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                reject(err);                
            }

            // reply will be nil when the key exists, on the contrary it will be "OK"
            resolve(reply);
        });
    });
}

async function unlock (resourse: string, uniqueStr: string) {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        redisClient.eval(unlockScript, 1, resourse, uniqueStr, (err: Error, reply: any) =>{
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                reject(err);
            }

            resolve(reply);
        });
    });
}

async function get (key: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>((resovle, reject) => {
        redisClient.get(key, (err: Error, reply: string) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                reject(err);
            }
            resovle(reply);
        })
    });
}

async function set (key: string, value: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>((resovle, reject) => {
        redisClient.set(key, value, (err: Error, reply: string) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                reject(err);
            }
            resovle(reply);
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to solve your problem is to execute all the actions (get, increment, set) performed by the add() function inside a transaction in order to achieve atomicity - this can be achieved in Redis with the following ways:

- Redis transactions (MULTI/EXEC/WATCH), with optimistic locking (retries)
- Redis Lua script: create a lua script that will perform the add function and execute it

Answer (score -1):

You are facing this problem because you are not waiting for each `IFFE` function to finish. Hence they run in parallel and will not give you the result you are looking for.

To solve this, you need to `await` on each of the IFFE function. Now we can `await` only if the function in `async`. So I have converted the IFFE function into normal function. Here is the implementation

```
async function run() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    await add();
  }
}

// I know incr command, this is just an example.
async function add() {
  let numStr = await get('num');
  let num = Number(numStr);
  num++;
  await set('num', String(num));
  console.log(num);
}

function get(key) {
  return new Promise((resovle, reject) => {
    redisClient.get(key, (err, reply) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        reject(err);
      }
      resovle(reply);
    });
  });
}

async function set(key, value) {
  return new Promise((resovle, reject) => {
    redisClient.set(key, value, (err, reply) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        reject(err);
      }
      resovle(reply);
    })
  });
}

async function runner() {
  await run();
  await run();
  await run();

}
runner();
```

Comment: er...Sometimes I can't ensure they run in parallel. Thank you so much.